# Is this Necessary to perform (-1 ) on IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT when you have your own Upgradableproxy.sol?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, openzeppelin

Recently I see a smart contract ( upgradable proxy.sol) in which developer use this :

```
contract UpgradableProxy is Proxy {
    event ProxyUpdated(address indexed _new, address indexed _old);
    event ProxyOwnerUpdate(address _new, address _old);

    bytes32 constant IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT =
        keccak256("HelloWorld.proxy.implementation");
    bytes32 constant OWNER_SLOT = keccak256("HelloWorld.proxy.owner");

    constructor(address _proxyTo) {
        setProxyOwner(msg.sender);
        setImplementation(_proxyTo);
    }
```

Here Developer not perform `keccak256(("HelloWorld.proxy.implementation") -1 )`, just like in case of Original EIP-1967: Standard Proxy Storage Slots

**Standard**

```
_IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT ==
         bytes32(uint256(keccak256("eip1967.proxy.implementation")) - 1))
```

**In My Code**

```
IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT =
        keccak256("HelloWorld.proxy.implementation")
```

So is this Mandatory in Every time you perform -1 after conversation to Keccak256 ?

Please Clear my Query

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

It's an additional security check.

When calculating the value of the slot that will contain the implementation address of the proxy, we are applying a `keccak256` function on this `"eip1967.proxy.implementation"` value. This should work well, but removing `1` after doing the hash makes it impossible to calculate a pre-image of this implementation slot.

From the "Rationale" of the [EIP-1967](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1967), this is what is written: "*Vyper seems to follow the same strategy as Solidity. Note that contracts written in other languages, or directly in assembly, may incur in clashes. They are chosen in such a way so they are guaranteed to not clash with state variables allocated by the compiler, since they depend on the hash of a string that does not start with a storage index. Furthermore, a -1 offset is added so the preimage of the hash cannot be known, further reducing the chances of a possible attack.*"